# Cannot create mixed index in JanusGraph

Tags: janusgraph

I'm using janusgraph 0.5.2 with Cassandra and elastic search. I wanted to create mixes indices.

I followed the docs and created my script as below. Basically I'm closing all open transactions and then creating the mixed index.

```
size = graph.getOpenTransactions().size();
for(i=0;i<size;i++) {graph.getOpenTransactions().getAt(0).rollback()}
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
taxNoKey = mgmt.getPropertyKey('taxNo')
mgmt.buildIndex('taxNo_mixed', Vertex.class).addKey(taxNoKey).buildMixedIndex("search")
mgmt.commit()
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, 'taxNo_mixed').status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED, SchemaStatus.ENABLED).call()
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("taxNo_mixed"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
mgmt.commit()
```

After `mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("taxNo_mixed"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()` It get the below error.

> ERROR org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementLogger  -
> Evicted [2@7f00010124289-ivis-SYS-7039A-I1] from cache but waiting too
> long for transactions to close. Stale transaction alert on:
> [standardjanusgraphtx[0x332460d4], standardjanusgraphtx[0x3de388c0],
> standardjanusgraphtx[0x39dc0ba4], standardjanusgraphtx[0x33efa7d4]]
> ==>org.janusgraph.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.scan.StandardScanMetrics@3054cdd3

1. My graph is not big, it contains 200k nodes and 400k edges
2. I'm copy-pasting to gremlin shell? Is it ok?
3. Should there be any specific settings in elastic search for creating an index?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: It seems like the index is created and active. I don't know why it shows this error. I checked the new index with the command `mgmt.printSchema()` and I see it is enabled and it works!

Answer (score 2):

JanusGraph can also have problems creating indices when one of the instances that once opened the graph, was not properly closed. JanusGraph has the following manual procedure to [force closure afterwards](https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/recovery/#janusgraph-instance-failure):

```
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
mgmt.getOpenInstances() //all open instances
==>7f0001016161-dunwich1(current)
==>7f0001016161-atlantis1 
mgmt.forceCloseInstance('7f0001016161-atlantis1') //remove an instance  
mgmt.commit()
```